# Removing StripSlash in Blade Ouput

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to remove the stripslash `"\"` character from my database search result.

Instead of using `{{stripslashes($output->var)}}`, which add a PHP function on every output in blade, can I do it GLOBALLY in the `BladeCompiler file`?

I want to apply this change in every output `{{ }}` in my Laravel site, any suggestion?  I tried to modify the `Bladecompiler` file `compileRegularEchos` function, seems not working, please advice

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you're using Laravel 5 because Blade templating defaults to escaping now. If you want to echo something without escaping you can use this syntax:

```
{!! $output->var !!}
```

For more info you can check the [Blade docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/templates#other-blade-control-structures)

Comment: hi, i am using laravel 4... but i just modify the bladecomplier and it remove the stripslashes on every output?

Comment: *just modify the bladecomplier* not good idea